# Need to crop canvas and not resize it using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas, overlay

I'm actually working on a project which overlay two image, with one that the user upload it and the second is by default.

My only problem is when the uploaded image is a rectangle and not a square, the canvas is resizing it. I need that the canvas crop my image, and be a square. Then I can apply the filter.

Here is my code:

```js
$('.file1, .file2').on('change', function() {
  var reader = new FileReader(),
    imageSelector = $(this).data('image-selector');

  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      imageIsLoaded(e, imageSelector)
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  }
});

$('.btn-merge').on('click', merge);

function imageIsLoaded(e, imageSelector) {
  $(imageSelector).attr('src', e.target.result);
  $(imageSelector).removeClass('hidden');
};

function merge() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),

    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    imageObj1 = new Image(),
    imageObj2 = new Image();
  canvas.width = 300;
  canvas.height = 300;
  imageObj1.src = $('.image1').attr('src');
  imageObj1.onload = function() {
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj1, 0, 0, 300, 300);
    imageObj2.src = $('.image2').attr('src');
    imageObj2.onload = function() {
      ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
      ctx.drawImage(imageObj2, 0, 0, 300, 300);
      var img = canvas.toDataURL('img/png');
      $('.merged-image').attr('src', img);
      var mergedimage = document.getElementById('mergedimage');
      $('.merged-image').removeClass('hidden');
      $("#downloadfinal").attr("href", mergedimage.src);
    }

  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid shadow">

  <div class="container d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
    <div class="row mb-1 ">
      <h2>Votre photo ici : </h2>
      <label class="custom ml-3 hover-underline-animation"> <input class="ml-2 file1" type="file" data-image-selector=".image1" />Selectionner un fichier</label>

    </div>
    <img class="image1 hidden mb-4" alt="abs" width="200px" height="auto" />
    <div class="row">

      <h2 class="mr-2 ">Filtre par défaut : </h2>


      <img alt="abs image3" width="200px" height="auto" src="img/filtre.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="otherfilter">

      <div class="row mt-5 mb-5">
        <h2 class="">Mettez un autre filtre ici : </h2>
        <label class="custom ml-3 hover-underline-animation"> <input class="ml-2 file2" type="file" data-image-selector=".image2" />Selectionner un fichier</label>
      </div>

      <img class="hidden image2" alt="ab" width="200px" height="auto" src="img/filtre.png">
    </div>

  </div>



  <br />
  <div class="text-center mb-5">
    <input class="btn-merge mb-3" type="button" value="Appliquer le filtre" />
    <br />
    <img class="merged-image hidden mb-3" id="mergedimage" alt="merged image" />
    <canvas id="canvas" class="hidden"></canvas>
    <br>
    <a class="btn-dl" id="downloadfinal" role="button" href="#" download="photo_profil_modifie">
      <i class="mr-2 bi bi-download"></i>Télécharger
    </a>

  </div>
```

Thanks for read this, hope my english is good, if you don't understand tell me.

Answer (score 2):

To do this you need to scale the input image to fit the canvas either horizontally or vertically while maintaining it's aspect ratio.

That's not hard to do as things are a bit easier since the canvas is squarish. Say we have a canvas of 300 x 300 pixel and we want to draw a non-square image of 400 x 300 onto. First we take the width or height of the canvas - it does not really matter as it's the same - and divide it by the bigger side of the image - 400 in this case.

```
300 / 400 == 0.75
```

This is the scale we need to multiply both the width and height of the image before drawing it onto the canvas.

Here's an example:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
let imageObj1 = new Image();
imageObj1.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';

imageObj1.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
imageObj1.onload = () => {
  let scale = imageObj1.width > imageObj1.height ? canvas.width / imageObj1.width : canvas.height / imageObj1.height;
  context.drawImage(imageObj1, canvas.width / 2 - imageObj1.width * scale / 2, canvas.height / 2 - imageObj1.height * scale / 2, imageObj1.width * scale, imageObj1.height * scale);
}
imageObj1.src = 'https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest=https://picsum.photos/id/237/300/400';
```

```css
#canvas {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

If you prefer to not have unused area on your canvas and stretch the image to the whole canvas and crop the exceess, you simply divide the smaller side of your image by the canvas width/height.

For example:

```js
//ctx.drawImage(imageObj1, 0, 0, 300, 300);let image = new Image();

let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
let imageObj1 = new Image();
imageObj1.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';

imageObj1.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
imageObj1.onload = () => {
  let scale = imageObj1.width < imageObj1.height ? canvas.width / imageObj1.width : canvas.height / imageObj1.height;
  context.drawImage(imageObj1, canvas.width / 2 - imageObj1.width * scale / 2, canvas.height / 2 - imageObj1.height * scale / 2, imageObj1.width * scale, imageObj1.height * scale);

}
imageObj1.src = 'https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest=https://picsum.photos/id/237/300/400';
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```